# Calling a PHP function by reference behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, function, pass-by-reference

Iwonder why the out put is 0(zero) for below code snippet? Can anyone please clarify why below code output is zero.

```
<?php
function a($number)
{
  return (b($number) * $number);
}

function b(&$number)
{
  ++$number;
}

echo a(5); // output 0(zero) ?
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never return any value from the function, and you're trying to `echo` the return value.

```
function b(&$number)
{
    return ++$number;
}
```

Note that this is a silly example for a function that takes its parameter by reference, since you don't have a reference to the original value `5`. Something like this would be more appropriate:

```
function b( &$number) {
    ++$number;
}

$num = 5;
b( $num);
echo $num; // Prints 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The function name is b, but you are calling a...

Also, you are echoing a function, that doesn't return a value. This means you are echoing a non-initialize variable.

You must either return a value:

```
    return ++$number;
```

or echo the variable directly:

```
    $number = 5;
    b($number);
    echo $number;
```